# Is there a breakdown of the simplification scheme into methods?

Tags: characters, simplified-characters

For the second round of simplification (actually, its second part), there is a scheme dividing the processes into classes by the method used, such as:

- leaving only part of the character that leaves the main impression;
- retain the form and smoothen fine details;
- replacing character altogether with a simpler one read similar;
- replacing only a phonetic with simpler one;
- use the hand-written form;
- replace altogether by a new ideographic composition;
  etc.

Is there a similar breakdown of how the simplifications were achieved for each particular one in the current list?

Answer (score 2):

The second round is just a continuation of the first, so the methods involved are quite similar. For a break down of each simplified character and their corresponding method, you can check the Simplified Character Table 《簡化字總表》.

There are three sub-tables, the [first one](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AE%80%E5%8C%96%E5%AD%97%E6%80%BB%E8%A1%A8%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%80%E8%A1%A8) contains simplifications that can not be used as rules to simplify radicals in other characters; the [second one](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AE%80%E5%8C%96%E5%AD%97%E6%80%BB%E8%A1%A8%E7%AC%AC%E4%BA%8C%E8%A1%A8) contains characters that can be applied to others; and the third one shows the result of such application of rules.

The first table is most relavent to your question: see the Simplification Method column (簡化方法). For example 改換聲旁 means "replacing phonetic radicals", 刪減偏旁 means "deleting radicals" (corresponding to the method "leaving only part of the character" in your list), and so on.